# PHP change array values to create new array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

this way how i get array from db:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$db_array = array();
// start fetch for words
if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $db_array[] = $row;
    }
}
```

My array looked like this:

```
Array
(
    [cat cute] => animal#cute animal
    [cat women] => film
)
```

How to add '{' and '}' to all values?
I wish i can get new array like this:

```
Array
(
    [cat cute] => {animal#cute animal}
    [cat women] => {film}
)
```

It's hard for me, i am new in php development.

Comment: This syntax doesn't look a lot like PHP.

Comment: Can u tell why you need { and } around your values, maybe you using template engine or js framework?

Comment: @Nerfair i have to deal with synonim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
$arr =  array
(
    'cat cute' => 'animal#cute animal',
    'cat women' => 'film'
);
array_walk($arr, function(&$item){
   $item = '{'.$item.'}'; 
});
print_r($arr);
```

Here is the link for [array_walk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

Answer (score 2):

Since you want a new array, try this:

```
<?php
array_map(function($value)
{
    return '{' . $value . '}';
}, $arr);
```

[`array_walk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) in [rahul_m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6556397/rahul-m)'s answer modifies your array, while [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) creates a new one.

Comment: Thank you for the way you answer in detail based from my question.